LM324n amplification during voltage follow
I've built simple Low-pass filter and voltage follower using LM324N amplifier. Upon my understanding, the voltage follower should not amplify the voltage, due to its gain=1. But it seriously shifts the dB range with amplification! When I try DC simulation, I saw it amplifies the input signal value to its maximum voltage within the common mode range(Vcc-2V). Why is this happening? How can I successfully transfer the filtered signal?



I think a good bit of your problem may just be unfamiliarity with LTspice.
The output window is not showing any gain, it is showing loss, although I can't tell where in the circuit you are measuring since the plot shows V(n007) and the output of the opamp is labeled OUT so you should be plotting V(out). Get in the habit of using named nets so the plot traces have meaningful names instead of just something like V(n007).
Your plot shows an AC analysis but I only see a .tran on the schematic. You should show the schematic that goes with the plot, I think yours are from two different runs with different settings.
You mention a DC analysis but don't show it. For a circuit like this a DC analysis isn't going to tell you much, it will just give you the static DC voltages in the circuit.
It would help to clean up the schematic a bit, flip the opamp so that the positive supply pin is at the top. Offset the net labels VCC and VEE from the opamp a bit by bringing a bit of wire out, they are too close and it's hard to tell if they are actually connected properly. Don't put a wire into a ground at a right angle, use a separate ground symbol for C3 instead of connecting it to the one for V3.
Also your opamp symbol doesn't look quite right for LTspice, is this a custom symbol for a third party model? If so that might be part of the problem. Try simulating with one of the opamp models that comes with LTspice first, get it working with that and then try substituting in the third party model.
Here's an example:

You might also add some load to the opamp output such as a 10k resistor to ground, or if you know what impedance you expect the opamp to drive use that value.

Thank you, the op amp I've used is indeed a third party model by someone in github. When I change it into universal op amp 2(with slew rate and limit), it works well.

You have the input terminals on the op amp wrong.  Your signal needs to go into the positive input terminal, and the feedback goes from the output to the negative input terminal.

It looks like the signal goes to + and feedback to -. The opamp is flipped so the power connections are - on top and + on bottom. The symbol doesn't look right, not sure if this is a self-made symbol for a third party model or what.
